# Android drawable animation?

Tags: android, animation, drawable, animationdrawable

Is it possible to do an animation like this :[Animation GIf](https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/480/1*hRJF5CNRG6tB-SkwVU5bCw.gif)

If possible could someone please guide me on that?

Comment: This might help you, use the combination of drawable animation library particle generating library, links are https://github.com/DenisMondon/easy-animated-vector-drawable?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=6200 and https://github.com/DanielMartinus/Konfetti?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5884

Comment: Can someone please tell me why the question is getting downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

[LikeButton](https://github.com/jd-alexander/LikeButton) library is desugned to create buttons like that.

First make sure you use the JitPack dependency url:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}
```

Then add this dependency to your app module build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
        ...
        compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:LikeButton:0.2.3'
    }
}
```

And use it in xml like:

```
<com.like.LikeButton
    app:icon_type="heart"
    app:icon_size="25dp"
    android:id="@+id/heart_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Then you'll get a view like this:

[image: Preview]

Comment: Thank you. It serves the purpose but I was looking for something without using a library...